# getting exception Authentication failed for token submission in apache shiro

Tags: java, shiro

i am new in apache shiro.i am getting exception when i execute this statement.

```
currentUser.login(token);
```

exception is

```
 errororg.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed for token submission [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - abc@gmail.com, rememberMe=true].  Possible unexpected error? (Typical or expected login exceptions should extend from AuthenticationException).
```

i am invoking this method for login.the code is.

```
  public boolean authorize(String username,String password)
{
    Boolean status=false;
    log.debug("the user id "+username+"passwrodD::"+password);
    Realm realm = new JdbcRealm();
    DefaultSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultSecurityManager(realm);
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password);
    token.setRememberMe(true);
    SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

    Response r = null;
    log.debug("before process for login");
    try
    {
        currentUser.login(token);   //This throws an error upon form submission

        r = Response.ok().entity(token).build();            

    }
    catch (UnknownAccountException uae ) {
        //username wasn't in the system, show them an error message?
        System.out.println("the user name is invalid");
    } catch ( IncorrectCredentialsException ice ) {
        //password didn't match, try again?
        System.out.println("the password name is invalid");
    } catch ( LockedAccountException lae ) {
        //account for that username is locked - can't login.  Show them a message?

    } catch ( AuthenticationException ae ) {
        //unexpected condition - error?
        System.out.println("unexpect error"+ae);
    }
    return status;
}
```

my shiro.ini file

```
 [main]
 jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
 jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
 jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery =select User_Password FROM  user_master where User_id=?
 ds = com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource
 ds.serverName = localhost
 ds.user = root
 ds.password = root
 ds.databaseName = test
 jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
 [users]
 [roles]
 [urls]
```

i include listener and filter in my web.xml file.
i change the authenticationQuery to my query. and when i am executing i am getting this above error. and also i do know is it right way to modify or override query.

Comment: and i want to implement only user login. and i want to skip the roll and permission query..this is possible?

Comment: yes this is possible..

Comment: hi.any body have an idea that if user login is success then i need to return the other infomation. how to do?

Comment: Take a look at [line 338 of this code](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-shiro/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/stormpath/shiro/realm/ApplicationRealm.java#L338) from [Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com). Note that after the user is successfully authenticated a `PrincipalCollection` with all the information about the user is added to the `SimpleAuthenticationInfo`. Then, you can retrieve the user information this way: `Map<String, Object> userInfo = SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipals().oneByType(java.util.Map.class);`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are missing `securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm` in your `shiro.ini`

Answer (score 0):

I just got this exception, and the problem was I was setting `securityManager.realm` incorrectly in `shiro.ini`.  This is what I had:

```
[main]
fooRealm = com.company.foo.Realm
securityManager.realms = fooRealm
```

This is what fixed it (I was missing a `$`):

```
[main]
fooRealm = com.company.foo.Realm
securityManager.realms = $fooRealm
```